# C# and Caliburn - RescueAttribute and Coroutines

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, caliburn, coroutine

I think I have found a situation where RescueAttribute is broken.  Or maybe I am using co-routines incorrectly.

I have a ViewModel like this:

```
[Rescue("Rescue")]
class MyViewModel
{
    //... left out some bus-logic code here ...

    public void Login()
    {
        yield return Show.Busy();

        //the following line will also cause the problem, just like AsyncResult
        //yield return Show.MessageBox("Test");

        yield return new AsyncResult(() => _server.Login());

        //throw new Exception("Aww, snap!");

        yield return Show.NotBusy();
    }

    public void Rescue(Exception exc)
    {
        //Show a messagebox or something
    }
}
```

AsyncResult is implemented like so:

```
using Exec = Caliburn.PresentationFramework.Invocation.Execute;

    public class AsyncResult : IResult
    {
        private readonly Action _function;

        public AsyncResult(Action function)
        {
            _function = function;
        }

        public void Execute(ResultExecutionContext context)
        {
            Exec.OnBackgroundThread(delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    _function();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Exec.OnUIThread(() => Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs { Error = exc, WasCancelled = true }));
                    return;
                }
                Exec.OnUIThread(() => Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs()));
            });
        }

        public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed = delegate { };
    }
```

If I uncomment the exception in my above ViewModel, Rescue fails to handle the exception.

Is this a bug in Caliburn, or is AsyncResult implemented wrong?

If you put an exception before the yield to return an AsyncResult, Rescue works just fine.  Also if the exception is thrown *on* the async thread, rescue still works!

EDIT: you can also use Show.MessageBox instead of AsyncResult to reproduce the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a legitimate bug. I added an issue for this in the Caliburn tracker: http://caliburn.codeplex.com/workitem/7636

**EDIT: the issue was fixed**
see: http://caliburn.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=234229

Comment: Thanks.  It took us a while to track this down to where I could make an easy example to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a change to the IDispatcher that might apply to this problem:

http://caliburn.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=223873